# How can i convert CookieContainer to KeyvaluePair?

Tags: vb.net, websocket, websocket4net

I wonder how can i CookieContainer to a KeyvaluePair, i got cookies from a website through HttpWebrequest. Now i want paste it to websocket4net.

Please ! see the image below

```
Dim logincookie As CookieContainer
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9lu1.png)

Comment: What does it want in the KeyValuePairs? Domain and Value?

Comment: api.xxxx.xxx/login how can i convert it ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. It's a KeyValuePair, two strings. What do need to provide as the Key and the related Value? It could be 1) Domain as Key and Cookie `Name=Value` as the Value. Or simply the `Cookie.Name` as the Key and the `Cookie.Value` as the Value. What is it?